# Current use of StackFlair

Tags: discussion, flair

In searching for ways to customize and improve the look of my flair, I have found numerous answers pointing to ***StackFlair*** as the option of choice.  However, StackFlair seems to be permanently shutdown, causing these answers to be out-of-date.

**Is StackFlair still available?**  **Are there alternatives** that are currently available and working?  What are the major differences between any alternatives?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I asked [Rebecca](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/140548/rebecca-chernoff) about this a while back and it doesn't seem like she'll be offering StackFlair anymore. However, after talking with her I've decided to try and fix any outstanding issues and rehost it*, so hopefully I can make that happen sometime this week.

While there's always [se-flair](https://stackapps.com/questions/2119/se-flair-html-combined-stack-exchange-site-flair) and the official flair you can find via the "flair" link in your profile, neither of these offer the same level of customization that StackFlair did.

<sub>*albeit on a different domain probably, because the current one is being squatted with a minimum $500 bid</sub>